# Using a ScheduledThreadPool with parallel execution

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Currently, I have an application that collects data every second and sends it to an API endpoint. To run every second, I am using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` that runs the thread which sends the data. The issue is the sending of the data sometimes takes more than one second, and this results in the next sequence of data to be collected more than a second later. Is there any way this can be changed (or other libraries can be used) so that even if a thread is not finished sending the data, another thread can start running in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to deal with the desire for overlapping executions of the same scheduled task is to execute the (time consuming) business logic of the task asynchronously.

In other words, when the once-per-second task is triggered, submit the real work to an ExecutorService (either the one you are using for the scheduled tasks or another one). This way, the scheduled task has already finished it's work (to queue the actual work) long before it is time for it to execute again.

Comment: So I'll call the data collection (which is very quick) task DATA, and the sending task (which takes longer) SEND. Is it considered "ok" practice if I have a global variable for the executor/pool for SEND, and schedule the sending directly via DATA when it is finished?

Comment: You would `scheduleAtFixedRate` a task. That task might do your "data" stuff and then `submit` a separate task that does the "send" for that data. In other words, you will have only one scheduled task and each time it executes you end up with a non-scheduled task that gets executed independently.

Comment: So with regards to the submitting, is there anyway I can prevent unlimited queuing from occuring?

Comment: You can control all aspects of how these tasks are queued and executed. If you want to, you can use a queue that will block when it reaches the capacity where you want to limit it. If you have problems with that, you probably should ask it as a separate question with all the details of what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, and what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not concerned about out of order invocations on the "API endpoint" then you can create the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with a `corePoolSize` > 1. In this way, every time the scheduler kicks in it will use the first available thread in the pool. And given a `corePoolSize` > 1 you would need several invocations to take more than 1s before you'd run out of threads.

For additional context: a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has a scheduling thread which checks for tasks and on finding one it delegates the task to a worker thread from its internal pool. If the internal pool has a single thread (i.e. `corePoolSize=1`) then all tasks are executed seriallly and you cannot guarantee that the tasks will be executed every `_wait_period_` (though you can be certain about ordering). If you want to insist on the tasks running on schedule and you are not concerned about ordering then you can configure the pool with a `corePoolSize` which ensures that there is always an available thread in the 'worker' pool every time the scheduler finds a task.

**Edit 1**: if you are using `scheduleAtFixedRate` then the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823250/8200937) which refers to delegating the scheduled invocation to a separate thread pool is an option. If you adopt this approach then `corePoolSize=1` will be sufficient since the 'worker' thread is then only reponsible for delegating the task to a separate pool.

Comment: I took a look at this but this is what I saw in the documentation for `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

"If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."

This is an issue, as I can't wait for the task to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Separate out the data collection and send tasks.
Data collection on a separate Thread pool (or a scheduled single thread) and submit the data to another pool whose job is to publish the data